# I am facing a syntax related problem while setting codeceptjs using webdriver.io for my test automation

Tags: webdriver-io, codeceptjs

The problem is with the config file where I'm setting port to open up chrome. I am following 1) https://codecept.io/webdriver/#what-is-selenium-webdriver and ran a test using: npx codeceptjs run.

```
const { setHeadlessWhen } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

    // turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
    // HEADLESS=true npx codecept run
    setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

    exports.config = {
      tests: './*_test.js',
      output: './output',
      helpers: {
        WebDriver: {
          url: 'www.fb.com',
          browser: 'chrome'
          host:'127.0.0.1',
          port: 4444,
          restart: false,
          windowSize: '1920x1680',
          desiredCapabilities: {
            chromeOptions: {
              args: [ /*"--headless",*/ "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" ]
            }
          },
        },
      }
      include: {
        I: './steps_file.js'
      },
      bootstrap: null,
      mocha: {},
      name: 'codecepjs',
      plugins: {
        wdio: {
          enabled: true,
          services: ['selenium-standalone']
        }
        retryFailedStep: {
          enabled: true
        },
        screenshotOnFail: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }

};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const { setHeadlessWhen } = require('@codeceptjs/configure');

// turn on headless mode when running with HEADLESS=true environment variable
// HEADLESS=true npx codecept run
setHeadlessWhen(process.env.HEADLESS);

exports.config = {
  tests: './*_test.js',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    WebDriver: {
      url: 'www.github.com',
      browser: 'chrome',
      host:'127.0.0.1',
      port: 4444,
      restart: false,
      keepBrowserState: true,
      keepCookies: true,
      windowSize: '1920x1680',
      desiredCapabilities: {
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [ /*"--headless",*/ "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" ]
        }
      },
    },
  },
  include: {
    I: './steps_file.js'
  },
  bootstrap: null,
  mocha: {},
  name: 'codecepjs',
  plugins: {
    wdio: {
      enabled: true,
      services: ['selenium-standalone']
    },
    retryFailedStep: {
      enabled: true
    },
    screenshotOnFail: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};
```